# Javascript Click on Svg/object element dosen't trigger with mobile

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Hi I have a problem getting click/touch to work show it will toggle a div in the DOM outside the Svg to show, on a element inside a svg, when using `object` to embed the SVG. I've tried many different ways but nothing do it. Are there a friendly person here, that can give me the correct way to do this

I have tried to use `touchstart` I've also tried another code I have, that is not used with svg that works on both desktop and mobile. But when I use that script for this, it can't read inside the svg. It dose feel like the problem is that the mobile doesn't read in svg the same way, and therefore the code doesn't work.

I did look though a lot of the post in here, but most of them have nothing to do with click events, and I really don't have the skill to rewrite them.

so here is the structure:
First I have my.

Under that I load the script ( I did try using it over the object, and in html head still nothing)

```
<object class="nSvg" type="image/svg+xml" data="img/emne.svg"></object>




<div id="boxOpen" class="boxOpenHidden">
    <div id="naturSkiferBruges">
        <h2>test</h2>
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var nSvg = document.getElementsByClassName("nSvg")[0];
   nSvg.addEventListener("load",function(){
               var sSvg = nSvg.contentDocument;
               var subEle = sSvg.getElementsByClassName("myclass")[0];
               subEle.addEventListener("click",function(){
                       $('#boxOpen').toggleClass('boxOpenVis');
                }, false);
             }, false);
</script>
```

Here is the svg element I'm trying to make a click on:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1920" height="2000" viewBox="0 0 1920 2000">
<text class="myclass" data-name="myclass" x="158.25" y="1298.112">Hvor kan Kobbertag et bruges?</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go buddy:

**HTML:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1920" height="2000" viewBox="0 0 1920 2000" class="nSvg">
  <text class="myclass" data-name="myclass" x="158.25" y="1298.112">Hvor kan Kobbertag et bruges?</text>
</svg>
```

**JS:**

```
   var Svg = document.getElementsByClassName("nSvg")[0];
   let texts = Svg.getElementsByClassName("myclass");

   for (text of texts) {
     text.addEventListener("click", function() {
       alert("OK");
     }, false);
   }
```

LIVE DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/mr39e54h/

> PS: Trying clicking on the text

**Update:**
You can bind an event on the loaded svg by traversing through the `children` of the `contentDocument`.

```
var nSvg = document.getElementsByClassName("nSvg")[0];
nSvg.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var text = nSvg.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0];
  text.addEventListener("click", function() {
     $('#boxOpen').toggleClass('boxOpenVis');
  }, false);
}, false);
```

Comment: Hi Salvino thanks for taking the time, but here comes the problem. I can get it to work as you did the same with my old code, but if you note I load the svg with object instead of having it in the html doc. the svg is local in image folder but it is the only way as I have many svg and if I write all of them in the html without using object the doc gets to heavy. is there a way to get the code to work when it is embed with object?

Comment: Do you have a remote link to that svg that we can directly try out?

Comment: Sure here. I don't know how to load it in codepen with as the object is local and I know it makes a difference if it's external 

https://tinghusogkoch.dk/undersider/test.html

the svg is located at https://tinghusogkoch.dk/test.svg

Comment: I updated my answer. I tried it on the site you provided and it seems to be working.

Comment: I've added the code you gave me and I can see it is giving a 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined" as far as I know `load` have to be used think I can remember I read that somewhere when searching an answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I couldn't use the load function because I was directly trying it in console. I have updated my answer with the load function. Can you try the above updated code?

Comment: @LasseFrederiksen I tried it in your site, and it seems to be working. Let us know in case you still can't proceed.

Comment: Salvino, you are a freaking star. I've used at least 7 hours reading and reading on this topic, trying to understand the way to work with different DOM's to get it to work and it's a problem I keep on getting, when I build websites as the html doc gets way to heavy with all the svg local.. Thank you for the time you have used to help me ! Much appreciated. and now I can see how it should be ,so I can build on that, just perfect.

Comment: Appreciate the words buddy! Thanks @LasseFrederiksen